# How to replace an injected Service in angular template when using from other component

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I have multiple Dialogs that looks exactly the same and differs in the backend service they communicate with.

I have written a template for the Dialog `BaseDialogComponenet` with a `BaseService` to communicate with. Now I want to reuse the BaseDialogComponent in other `theOtherComponenet` with other Service. How could I replace the `BaseService` injected in `BaseDialogComponenet.ts` with my `ModifiedService`in the `theOtherComponenet`.
Coming from Java and Spring world I would let the BaseService and the ModifiedService implemet an Interface with the desired methods and then replace the Services using  a qualifier

How can I replace the injected service in a template with angular?

Comment: could you provide some code of how you render your dialogs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood correctly you could do like this:

Your BaseDialogComponent:

```
@Component({})
export class BaseDialogComponent {
    constructor(base: BaseService) {}
}
```

Your theOtherComponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-other-comp',
    template: '<app-base-diag></app-base-diag>',
    providers: [{provide: BaseService, useClass: ModifiedService}]
})
export class theOtherComponent {
   constructor(){}
}
```

By doing this you're telling the dependency injector to provide a ModifiedService in place of a BaseService for all the children components of your `theOtherComponent`.

For more details on how it works i let you read the angular documentation:
https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#providers
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers

Edit:

As pointed by @enno.void a new instance of your ModifiedService will be created for every `theOtherComponent`.
You could use instead: `{provide: BaseService, useExisting: ModifiedService}` that would use the same `ModifiedService` created by the DI at the root.

Comment: But this implies that ever instance of theOtherComponent get its own instance of ModifiedService.